# Kadane's Algorithm in Scheme (Racket)

Tags: algorithm, scheme, racket, kadanes-algorithm

I understand the logic behind how Kadane's Algorithm (maximum sum of all sequential sub-arrays in an array) works in "pseudo-code," and I'm sure I could implement it as a function in C or C++. However, I'm trying to implement it using lists in Scheme (Racket; the file extension is .rkt), which I have no experience with.

The end result I'm looking for is...

```
Input: (maxsum `(1 4 -2 1))
Output: 5
```

So far I've developed two helper functions I may be able to use within the maxsum function.

(1) size: returns the number of elements in a list.

```
(define size
   (lambda (list)
      (cond
         [(not (list? list)) 0]
         [(null? list) 0]
         [else (+ 1 (size (cdr list)))]
      )
   )
)
```

(2) sum: returns the sum of all elements in a list.

```
(define sum
   (lambda (list)
      (cond
         [(not (list? list)) 0]
         [(null? list) 0]
         [else (+ (car list) (sum (cdr list)))]
      )
   )
)
```

How would I go about defining/designing the maxsum function?

Comment: I have some doubt about "sequential sub-arrays". What would be "sequential sub-arrays" of (1, 2, 3, 4) ?

Comment: What I mean by "sequential sub-array" is a sub-array extracted from an array made up of sequential elements in that array.

If your array was comprised of (1, 2, 3, 4), then a sequential sub-array could be (1, 2), or (2, 3), or (3, 4), or (1, 2, 3), etc. However, the sub-array (1, 3, 4) would not be a "sequential" sub-array because 1 and 3 are not next to each other in the given array.

Basically, if you put a single set of parentheses around any number of elements within an array, the elements within those parentheses will be a "sequential sub-array" of the given array.

Comment: Is full array (1 2 3 4) also included in sub-arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version patterned after the [Phyton code on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm):

```
(define (maxsum lst)
  (define (aux lst max-ending-here max-so-far)
    (if (null? lst)
        max-so-far
        (let ((new-max-ending-here (max 0 (+ (car lst) max-ending-here))))
          (aux (cdr lst) new-max-ending-here (max max-so-far new-max-ending-here)))))
  (aux lst 0 0))

(maxsum '(1 4 -2 1))   ; => 5

(maxsum '(-2 1 -3 4 -1 2 1 -5 4))  ; => 6
```

It is tail recursive, so it will be compiled into an efficient iterative program.

Comment: Thanks! DrRacket doesn't seem to like nested definitions for some reason, but if I separate aux into its own definition, maxsum works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Almost literal translation of [Python code][1] to Racket:

```
(define (max_subarray A)
  (define-values (max_ending_here max_so_far) (values 0 0))
  (for ((x (in-list A)))
    (set! max_ending_here (max 0 (+ max_ending_here x)))
    (set! max_so_far (max max_so_far max_ending_here)))
  max_so_far)
```

Testing:

```
(max_subarray  `(1 4 -2 1))
(max_subarray  '(-2 1 -3 4 -1 2 1 -5 4))
```

Output:

```
5
6
```

Please note that recursive functions are generally preferred over iterative ones in Racket and use of "`set!`" is discouraged here.

Following uses higher functions like `apply` and `map` for different steps:

```
(define (maxsum lst)
  (define subarrays
    (for*/list ((start (length lst))
                (len (range 1 (- (add1(length lst)) start))))
      (take (drop lst start) len)))
  (define sumlist (map (λ (x) (apply + x)) subarrays))
  (apply max sumlist))
```

Following is more verbose form:

```
(define (maxsum lst)
  (define subarrays
    (for*/list ((start (length lst))
                (len (range 1 (- (add1(length lst)) start))))
      (take (drop lst start) len)))
  (displayln "\n----- SUBARRAYS ---------")
  (displayln subarrays)
  (define sumlist (map (λ (x) (apply + x)) subarrays))
  (displayln "----- SUMS OF SUBARRAYS ---------")
  (displayln sumlist)
  (display "MAX SUM:")
  (apply max sumlist))
```

Testing:

```
(maxsum  `(1 4 -2 1))
(maxsum  '(-2 1 -3 4 -1 2 1 -5 4))
```

Output:

```
----- SUBARRAYS ---------
((1) (1 4) (1 4 -2) (1 4 -2 1) (4) (4 -2) (4 -2 1) (-2) (-2 1) (1))
----- SUMS OF SUBARRAYS ---------
(1 5 3 4 4 2 3 -2 -1 1)
MAX SUM:5

----- SUBARRAYS ---------
((-2) (-2 1) (-2 1 -3) (-2 1 -3 4) (-2 1 -3 4 -1) (-2 1 -3 4 -1 2) (-2 1 -3 4 -1 2 1) (-2 1 -3 4 -1 2 1 -5) (-2 1 -3 4 -1 2 1 -5 4) (1) (1 -3) (1 -3 4) (1 -3 4 -1) (1 -3 4 -1 2) (1 -3 4 -1 2 1) (1 -3 4 -1 2 1 -5) (1 -3 4 -1 2 1 -5 4) (-3) (-3 4) (-3 4 -1) (-3 4 -1 2) (-3 4 -1 2 1) (-3 4 -1 2 1 -5) (-3 4 -1 2 1 -5 4) (4) (4 -1) (4 -1 2) (4 -1 2 1) (4 -1 2 1 -5) (4 -1 2 1 -5 4) (-1) (-1 2) (-1 2 1) (-1 2 1 -5) (-1 2 1 -5 4) (2) (2 1) (2 1 -5) (2 1 -5 4) (1) (1 -5) (1 -5 4) (-5) (-5 4) (4))
----- SUMS OF SUBARRAYS ---------
(-2 -1 -4 0 -1 1 2 -3 1 1 -2 2 1 3 4 -1 3 -3 1 0 2 3 -2 2 4 3 5 6 1 5 -1 1 2 -3 1 2 3 -2 2 1 -4 0 -5 -1 4)
MAX SUM:6
```